# Navigation always opens external browser with whitelist set to all

Tags: android, cordova

I have all URLs whitelisted in my config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

And I am attempting to open my webapp in the default index.js onDeviceReady handler like so:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    window.open('http://redacted.address.com');
}
```

However, every time I launch my application it just immediately opens an external browser with my provided link. This is using the android emulator.

How do I make it open in the internal web view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be rather poorly documented, but I have found the answer. I needed to add this line to my config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://redacted.address.com/*" />
```